# Python, Selenium, SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

can someone see what I'm doing wrong here? How would the code be right???

```
list_id=["HGD4HJ","9NA3HQ","EWCTUQ","B9VB62"]

browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(),{str(list_id[1])})]/../td[11]/div/a").click()
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//*[contains(text(),9NA3HQ)]/../td[11]/div/a" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

Thanks...

Comment: What is list_id[1] ? Also you can't trigger click on elements, instead it should be element

Comment: a list. look update....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'` at the beginning and at the end.
The XPath based on `contains(text())` is generally looking like

```py
//*[contains(text(),'the_text')]
```

while your expression is missing the opening `'` and closing `'`.
Try if this will be correct:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(),`{str(list_id[1])}`)]/../td[11]/div/a").click()
```

**UPD**
In case the above solution didn't work try this please

```py
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),`" + str(list_id[1]) + "`)]/../td[11]/div/a").click()
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Did you use the latest, current version?

Comment: yes i have seen. Unfortunately: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//*[contains(text(),`9NA3HQ`)]/../td[11]/div/a" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
`

Comment: In your comment here I see 9NA3HQ as not a part of entire `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//*[contains(text(),9NA3HQ)]/../td[11]/div/a" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. ` string. Are you sure you have `'` before and after the `{str(list_id[1])}` substring inside the xpath expression?

Comment: I have now tried your UPD. It makes no difference. `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//*[contains(text(),`9NA3HQ`)]/../td[11]/div/a" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`obviously selenium cannot combine a "contains" with a variable. it doesn't work on other websites either...

Comment: Are you sure you copied my answer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

if your list

```
list_id = ["HGD4HJ","9NA3HQ","EWCTUQ","B9VB62"]
```

contains string args, you don't need to convert again while passing into the xpath.

```
list_id=["HGD4HJ","9NA3HQ","EWCTUQ","B9VB62"]
browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{list_id[0]}')]/../td[11]/div/a").click()
```

the above should help you get past your issue.

Comment: I don't know if I don't convert this comes: `browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(),'{html_such_id[1]}')]/../td[11]/div/a").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: okay there was a type, try again I have updated above, it should have been `find_element` instead of `find_elements`

Comment: Unbelievable, just a single "s". Jip that was it. Now it's working. I've already tried a detour via "CTRL + F", "TAB" etc. but yes it was "s". Many thanks.......